# Use of the java.awt.Dimension class

Tags: java, awt, rectangles, dimension

I would like to use `Dimension` class (`java.awt.Dimension`), but it supports only integers. I want make Rectangle and Square classes like these:

Constructor:

```
public Rectangle(Dimension dim(double A, double B)) {
    // constructor code
}
```

Is it better to write my own implementation of the Dimension class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use `java.awt.Dimension` just because it happens to provide an interface that looks similar to the one you need. As the introduction says in [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dimension.html):

> The Dimension class encapsulates the width and height of a component ... in a single object.

By *component*, a [Java AWT Component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html) is meant. It seems weird to use a `java.awt.Dimension` for anything else.

If you provide your own implementation of `java.awt.Dimension`, it must adhere to the same interface as the one provided by the Java Runtime environment. So you do not gain anything. BTW, there is no need to provide your own implementation of `java.awt.Dimension`, the Java Runtime environment already provides a perfectly suitable implementation.

Write your own class that can handle float values as width and height.

Answer (score 4):

See [**JavaDoc**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dimension.html):

> The `Dimension` class encapsulates the width and height of a component
>   (**in integer precision**) in a single object.

So, if you need a Dimension class holding width and height in floating point precision, you can't use `java.awt.Dimension`. Looking at the Methods `java.awt.Dimension` provides it should be fairly easy to provide an own implementation.

Comment: and is there any way to extends this class (redefine constructor), or I have to make my own class (completely).

Comment: @user2490538: You _can_ extend the class, but you can't reuse any of it's methods, so it makes no sense. You have to implement all methods anyway, so you have to write a whole no class anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Dimension.setSize(double,double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dimension.html#setSize%28double,%20double%29) instead.